# Divs inside divs inside divs?

Tags: css, html

Ive made an image describing the issue

www.techagesite.com/divs.png
[image]

What im trying to do is have a container div with 2 divs side by side in the container. Then the right div will have 2 divs inside it one on top of each other.

The 2 divs in the container need to stack when the browser runs out of room but the 2 divs in the right div will always stay stacked.

Ive tried having the container at 100% and the 2 divs in the container at 50% float left but im unsure of what to have the 2 divs in the right div set up like.

Leaving the 2 divs in the right div without any css just messes up half my page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like divs...

Comment: picture is ok, also show your code so its easyier for us to help you

Comment: and a jsfiddle would be useful too

Comment: http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/DHmkp I LOVE DIVS!

Comment: yeah i probably should of but i didnt think it would be necessary

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="half-container">
    </div>
    <div class="half-container">
         <div class="split-right-half-container">
         </div>
         <div class="split-right-half-container">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS of:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.half-container {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:100%

}
.split-right-half-container {
    height:50%;
}
```

You would need to set the `.container` height to what you wish, e.g. `height:100px` as it is in the CSS or something else.

It can be seen here, although to put the borders in I had to make the `split-right-half-container { height:49px;}` http://jsfiddle.net/wj8pN/

Answer (score 1):

[Here's what you could do](http://jsfiddle.net/DTe57/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='top'>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  height:80%;
  width:80%;
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
}

.left{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background:lightblue;
}

.right{
  width:48%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background:yellow;
  padding:1%;
}

.top, .bottom{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}

.top{
  background:green;
}

.bottom{
  background:purple;
}
```

Comment: It might be because of my divs contents. Cant post because its too long. Could you have a look at line 823 http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work11122.htm i used your example code

Answer (score 0):

Two side-by-side divs need a width and they have to be floated. Also, under your divs, you need an element with the css attribute `clear: both;`

Here's a jsfiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RzKe/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LmcE2/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-col">left</div>
    <div class="right-col">
        <div class="box">upper</div>
        <div class="box">lower</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width:500px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:orange;
        border:3px solid red;
    }
    .left-col,
    .right-col {
        background-color:#5DA0E6;
        float:left;
        width:48%;
        min-height:200px;
        margin:1%;
    }
    .box {
        background-color:blue;
        min-height:100px;

    }
    .box:first-child {
        background-color:green;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {
        .wrapper {
            width:100%;
        }
        .left-col,.right-col {
            width:98%;
            margin:0;
            float:none;
        }
    }

</style>
```